# Data from DateTimeField() to TimeField() leaving only the time in the latter without the date?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Good morning!

I have a django database model table.

To fill this model table, data replenishment is used - a form in the template.

One of the columns from this model table is a DateTimeField() data type.

I also have a second table, the Django database model.

The differences from the first table described above are minimal - just an additional added column - which has a TimeField() data type.

I plan to copy from the first model - part of the data from the DateTimeField() column to the second table of the model - into the column - which has the data type TimeField().

I'm planning to copy some of the DateTimeField() data - just the time without the date.

Data from DateTimeField() to TimeField() leaving only the time in the latter without the date.

How can you come up with something for this?

Comment: the `strftime` may help you.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the `time` from `datetime field`, You may use this:

```
import datetime

datetime_field = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 5, 19, 18, 6, 485592)
date_only_field = datetime_field.date()
time_only_field = datetime_field.time()
```

You may also replace microseconds or seconds with `.replace()` function.

```
datetime_field = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 5, 19, 18, 6, 485592) 
time_only_field = datetime_field.time().replace(microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract time from DateTime object, by calling **.time()** method.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
     created_at = models.DateTimeField()
     ...

class ModelB(models.Model):
     created_time = models.TimeField()
     ...
```

```
obj_a = ModelA.objects.get(pk=1)
only_time = obj_a.created_at.time()
```